# ¿Expresa la segunda acepción de "cierto" lo contrario de la primera?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, acepciones

Acabo de darme cuenta de lo siguiente:

> **[cierto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Bb7pPO)**
>
> Del latín *certus*.
>
> 1. adj. Conocido como verdadero, seguro, indubitable.
>
> 2. adj. U. precediendo inmediatamente al sustantivo en sentido indeterminado. *Cierto lugar. Cierta noche.*

Estas son las dos primeras acepciones de la palabra. Si os fijáis, la segunda es todo lo contrario de la primera, dado que pasamos de algo "seguro e indubitable" a algo "indeterminado", es decir, "inseguro y dubitable".

¿Es esto así? ¿Se usa "cierto lugar" para indicar que no sabes exactamente dónde sucedió algo, o para indicar que lo sabes pero no quieres decirlo? En el primer caso, ¿cómo llegó "cierto" a tener esas dos variantes tan diferenciadas?

Comment: Yo siempre lo he imaginado de la segunda manera que comentas: para indicar que lo sabes pero no quieres decirlo, o que al menos no es algo importante. Últimamente lo oigo con rintintín: "Hay cierta persona que hoy no limpió los platos...", "Cierta persona no estará contenta con que el Madrid haya ganado...".

Comment: Certus significaba algo como «determinado». Algo determinado quedaba verificado, es decir, cierto/verdadero.  Lo curioso es que determinado es autoantónimo algo como cierto: *en un determinado lugar*... (Es decir, quedar indeterminado jajajaja).

Comment: Ciertamente este caso determina que el castellano es tan amplio, rico y flexible para que en determinadas ocasiones ciertos enunciados se presten a esta deliciosa ironía de la gimnasia sintáctica! ¡amo mi lengua madre! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No son realmente antónimos, porque los une su etimología. Vienen del latín **cernere**, que significaba "separar, discriminar, seleccionar, decidir" y están emparentadas con *cernir* y *discernir*. El participio **certus** significaba "decidido".

O sea, en ambos casos hay una base general y abstracta con múltiples posibilidades, de las cuales se separa o selecciona una específica. Solo que hay distintos "tipos" de certeza, dependiendo de la posición con respecto al sustantivo:

**Idea cierta**: De todas las ideas posibles separamos ésta específica, definitiva y segura. De ahí que este *cierto* sea sinónimo de *verdadero*.

**Cierta idea**: De todas las ideas posibles separamos una que conocemos pero no hemos detallado aún. Que todavía sea indeterminada en mi oración no quiere decir que sea *falsa, provisional* o *insegura*.

Darwin tuvo *cierta idea genial*. Esta idea es indeterminada por ahora, en mi discurso, hasta que la detalle si así lo deseo. Eso no quiere decir que tal idea sea falsa, ni que tú, yo o Darwin no sepamos realmente cuál es.

Answer (score 5):

*Cierto* como *verdadero, seguro* no se opone directamente al otro significado. *Cierto lugar* no es exactamente un lugar indefinido, sino lugares que el hablante prefiere no especificar pero que tiene (o finge tener) en mente. *En cierto lugar de La Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme*, etc. *Ciertas personas* apunta también, claramente, a individuos particulares, sea explícitamente definidos o definidos por inclusión en un grupo caracterizado.

Si alguien me comenta: *Al salir vi a ciertas personas*, me quedaré esperando que me diga quiénes son, porque es evidente que apunta a eso; al contrario, si me comentase: *Al salir vi a unas personas*, la frase me sugeriría que no se trata de nadie en particular, sino que lo que hay de interés es simplemente que vio a alguien, y no encontró, como quizá esperaba, la calle desierta.

A lo que voy es que *cierto lugar*, *cierta persona*, *ciertas cosas*, etc. refieren semánticamente a algo definido, concreto (*cierta cosa* se opone a *cualquier cosa*). La ambigüedad o inseguridad se da en otro plano.

No conozco la respuesta a la pregunta de cómo o cuándo estos dos significados comenzaron a usarse. Los mismos ocurren también en la palabra inglesa *[certain](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=certain)* al menos desde el siglo XVIII (la palabra en sí entró al inglés vía el francés en el siglo XIII), con lo cual éste no es fenómeno exclusivo de las lenguas romances.

Answer (score 1):

Son diversos los adjetivos cuyo significado varía según sean antepuestos o pospuestos al sustantivo.

"cierto" significa "verdadero" cuando aparece después del sustantivo:

- Su temor es cierto.
- Siento un temor cierto de que algo pueda ocurrir.

Antepuesto, adquiere el significado de "indeterminado", "indefinido" o "inespecífico", similar a "algún":

- La embarga (un) cierto temor de que algo pueda ocurrir.